# Group by date field in solrj

Tags: solrj

i want to group the output i am getting through date  type. But i am storing the data in solr using datetime type. Date Format i am using is

```
          Date format :: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

 For e.g. Date is stored in solr as "2013-03-01T20:56:45.000+00:00"
```

What i want as output is count of dates :: for .e.g.

```
   Date1:: "2013-03-01T20:56:45.000+00:00"
   Date2:: "2013-03-01T21:56:45.000+00:00"
   Date3:: "2013-03-01T22:56:45.000+00:00"
   Date3:: "2013-03-02T22:56:45.000+00:00"
   Date4:: "2013-03-02T23:56:45.000+00:00"
```

So i want the output as two columns ::

```
     Date           Count
     2013-03-01       3  
     2013-03-02       2
```

Here is the code i am using

```
    String url = "http://192.168.0.4:8983/solr";
SolrServer server = new HttpSolrServer(url);
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();


query.setQuery("*:*");
query.addFilterQuery("sessionStartTime:[2013-03-01T00:00:00Z TO 2013-03-04T24:00:00Z]");

query.add("group", "true");
query.add("group.field","uniqueId"); // uniqueId is grouping the data 
query.add("group.main","true");
query.setRows(9999);

QueryResponse rs=server.query(query);

Iterator<SolrDocument> iter = rs.getResults().iterator();
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: if you are on solr 4.x you could try pivot faceting: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HierarchicalFaceting

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an older question but I am working on something related to this so I thought I would share my solution.  Since you are using grouping, `rs.getResults()` will likely be null.  After reading through the SolrJ API and doing some testing on my end, you will find that the results are indeed grouped as you want them to be.  To access them, create a variable like such:

```
List<Group> groupedData = rs.getGroupResponse().getValues().get(0).getValues()
```

Note that `Group` is the class `org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.Group`

Then, iterate through `groupedData`, usinig `groupedData.get(i).getResult()` to get a `SolrDocumentList` of results for each grouped value.  In your example, (assuming the data is ordered as you said it would be), `groupedData.get(0)` would give you a `SolrDocumentList` of the three matches that have the date 2013-03-01.

I understand that this is quite the chain of method calls but it does end up getting the results to you.  If anyone does know a faster way to get to the data, please feel free to let me know as I would like to know as well.

Refer to the API for [GroupResponse](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/5_2_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/response/GroupResponse.html#getValues()) for more information

Note that this answer is working on Solr 5.4.0

Answer (score 0):

The output that you are trying to achieve, I believe is better suited to [Faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview) over grouping. Check out the documentation on [Date Faceting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Date_Faceting_Parameters) more specifically and SolrJ fully supports faceting, see [SolrJ - Advanced Usage](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj#Advanced_usage). For an introduction to  Faceting I would recommend reading [Faceted Search with Solr](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview)

Comment: Hi Paige, i am using faceting over grouping ... but i am getting null when i try to fetch the count of number of entries in a single group...
 query.add("group", "true");
 query.add("group.field","uniqueId");
 //query.add("group.field","sessionStartTime");
 query.add("group.field","sessionStartTime");
 query.add("group.main","true");
 query.add("group.ngroups","true");
 query.add("group.facet","true");
 
 query.setRows(9999); but when i try to do queryResponse.getGroupResponse() it gives me null.